# iOS Swift - CLGeocoder completionHandler block

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation, clgeocoder, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to parse a location (CLLocation) into a String.

```
    func locationToString (currentLocation: CLLocation) -> String? {
    var whatToReturn: String?
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            let location = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            whatToReturn = "\(location.locality) \(location.thoroughfare) \(location.subThoroughfare)"

        }
    })
    return whatToReturn
}
```

Obviously, whatToReturn always returns null, because completionHandler runs in the background.
I'm having a hard time understanding how do I update my String when completionHandler finishes?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your end goal with the string?  This will have to be triggered somewhere in the completion block.

Comment: I want to use the string (whatToReturn) and patse it into a textField. 
But, I'm not using this method from the controller itself, so I need a way to update the returned string...

Comment: The best way to do that is probably to just set your textField's text within the completion block.  [See Answer]

Comment: The best? I'm sure it not. It's the easiest (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your string in a textField, like indicated in your comments, do this:

```
func getAndDisplayLocationStringForLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            let location = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.textField.text = "\(location.locality) \(location.thoroughfare) \(location.subThoroughfare)"

        }
    })
}
```

However, if you need access elsewhere, perhaps pass a closure as an arg:

```
func getAndDisplayLocationStringForLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation, withCompletion completion: (string: String?, error?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            let location = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            completion(string: "\(location.locality) \(location.thoroughfare) \(location.subThoroughfare)", error: nil)

        } else {
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    })
}
```

Then call like this:

```
yourModel.getAndDisplayLocationStringForLocation(someLocation) { (string: String?, error: NSError?) -> () in
    if (error == nil) {
        self.textField.text = string
    }
}
```

You may want to handle error etc. differently.  This should be enough to get you started.

Comment: My bad, the error came of another part of my code. Thank you very much!
Although, I have to ask, why was is built that way? I mean using reverseGeocodeLocation should be used from the model but completionHandler seems it was meant to be used from the controller.

Comment: I can't speak for apple, but anytime there's a network operation required, the operation is backgrounded with a completion block to avoid blocking the UI for an indeterminate amount of time.