# Swift syntax - closures

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, closures

I am a bit struggling to construct a call in SWIFT for this function

```
func addressFromLocation(location:CLLocation!, completionClosure:((NSDictionary?)->())){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in
        var geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
        geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placeMarks, error) -> Void in
            if let places = placeMarks {
                var marks = places[0] as! CLPlacemark
                completionClosure(marks.addressDictionary)
            }else {
                completionClosure(nil)
            }

        })
    })
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: can you give some more explanation on what you're trying to construct.?

Comment: @arthankamal I wanna call that function, so to construct a call according to SWIFT syntax which I am not sure how to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27750189/1866077, hope this helps

Comment: @arthankamal thanx, but I am wondering how to call this function with this specific closure.

Comment: call you function with `addressFromLocation(location, completionClosure: {
            yourDict in
            // your code
        })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can remove unnecessary parentheses from `completionClosure` parameter type:

```
func addressFromLocation(location: CLLocation!, completionClosure: NSDictionary? -> ()){
    //...
}
```

And you can call this function like so:

```
addressFromLocation(location, completionClosure: {
    dict in
    // your code
})
```

Or even simpler because if closure is final argument of function then you can use trailing closure syntax:

```
addressFromLocation(location) {
    dict in
    // your code
}
```

And if you are do not need named parameter `dict` then you can refer parameter by number:

```
addressFromLocation(location) {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right with those parentheses. And thank you, works fine.