# CLGeocodeCompletionHandler

Tags: ios, swift, location, clgeocoder

So i am trying to have it do something after the completion handler but i keep getting an error:

> expected `CLGeocodeCompletionHandler`

```
class func didCompleteGeocoding(placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?, error: NSError?, completion: (results: Bool) -> Void){
   if error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {
        let placemark = placemarks![0] as! CLPlacemark
        let geocodedLocation = placemark.location!

   //some more code here
   }
   var geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
   var placemarks: [CLPlacemark]?

   func getlocation(){
   let cordinates = geoCoder.geocodeAddressString(locationtext, completionHandler: toSearchandPost2.didCompleteGeocoding(placemarks, error: nil, completion: { (results) -> Void in
           if results == true{
             // do something here
           }
    }))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use that function directly. Please have a look at the below code:

```
func getAndDisplayLocationStringForLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation) {
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(currentLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
        if error == nil && placemarks.count > 0 {
            let location = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            self.textField.text = "\(location.locality) \(location.thoroughfare) \(location.subThoroughfare)"

        }
    })
}
```

And you need to call it like this:

```
yourModel.getAndDisplayLocationStringForLocation(someLocation) { (string: String?, error: NSError?) -> () in
    if (error == nil) {
        self.textField.text = string
    }
}
```

Please at the below link for complete answer. However, the above code will be enough.

Reference: [iOS Swift - CLGeocoder completionHandler block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27749854/ios-swift-clgeocoder-completionhandler-block)